# Elixir: HTTPResponseStream to consume streaming API

Tags: http, stream, elixir, twitter-streaming-api

I want to write a client which can consume streaming APIs. Essentially, have a getter that returns an HTTPResponseStream instead of HTTPResponse. I couldn't find one in HTTPotion, so I figured I'd give it a try instead. But I have no idea how to go about it, and would really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 3):

You can do async requests with HTTPotion like so:

```
%HTTPotion.AsyncResponse{ id: id } = HTTPotion.get "http://example.com", [], [stream_to: self]
```

This will send messages of three different types to the current process (which is defined above via `self`):

```
# First, the response headers
%HTTPotion.AsyncHeaders{ id: ^id, status_code: 200, headers: _headers }
# Then, one or more chunks
%HTTPotion.AsyncChunk{ id: ^id, chunk: _chunk }
# And finally, an end message
%HTTPotion.AsyncEnd{ id: ^id }
```

The id can be used to handle the responses from multiple ongoing requests.